# Syntax error near "else" in Verilog. I can't figure out what the error is

Tags: fpga, verilog, programming, system-verilog, error

[image]

Create a scheme in which the counter would start counting "forward" five cycles, then "backward" two cycles from the loaded value by the EN signal.

It returns an error. Help me fix it, please.

[image]

Comment: You should probably show us the line that has the syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

You have a semicolon after `if (clk == 1)` that shouldn't be there. That's why I would recommend keeping the `begin` on the same line as the `if` to make it clear a semicolon isn't needed.

---

As an aside, `if (clk == 1)` inside an `always @ (clk)` block is undoubtedly a mistake. You should only do that sort of check for an asynchronous reset signal, not for the clock.